# Least squares more efficient than maximum likelihood?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, estimators

I have synthetic data which is sampled from a non-central chi distribution (similar to what is obtained experimentally). I am fitting a non-linear model to this data to extract three parameters of interest. I have tried both least squares and maximum likelihood, and based on my simulations I have been getting slightly higher mean-squared error from the maximum likelihood method over the least squares method. I find this result very surprising, since MLE has a bunch of nice properties that least squares does not.

(I would provide the code to reproduce it but it's quite lengthy due to the model / synthetic data, but I could work on getting a minimum reproducible example if need be.)

**My question:** Does this make sense? Most results I've seen online show that MLE is more efficient (i.e., lower MSE) than least squares, except under certain conditions where they're equivalent. Those conditions are not fulfilled here. In order to maximize the likelihood (or minimize least squares) I am using the basinhopping routine in `scipy.optimize`. I have checked extensively and both methods are converging to what I believe is a global optima. Any other ideas?

Comment: One property MLE does *not* generally have is to minimize estimation variance (that's irrelevant to most likelihoods), so such results are not at all surprising.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your input. Is there any procedure for finding an estimator that does minimize estimation variance?

Comment: This seems to be a "physics" thing to want to fit random samples from a probability distributions with least squares.  I understand the code might be too long to share but can you provide a sample dataset?  I ask because the error is certainly not constant and so I'm not seeing that a mean square error would necessarily be a good measure of goodness of fit (especially if, say, you might have more interest in a particular region of the distribution).

Comment: That's called an "MVUE" -- search our site for approaches or research the literature.

Comment: whether you least squares or MLE, the approaches are not equivalent  because the objectives are different. The only time you'd expect them to be the same is if you generated data that was normally distrobuted. In that case, least squares and maximum likelihood are equivalent.  Other than that, I don't know if there's any theory that says , in the non-normal case which you would expect to give better MSE ? I would actually think least squares because it's objective function is an estimated MSE.

Comment: @whuber I know what "MVUE" is and I should have been more precise than "least squares". What I mean is that it seems to be a "physics" thing (and maybe "engineering", too) to estimate the parameters of a probability distribution with a regression on a histogram.  At least that's how I'm interpreting "fitting a non-linear model to this data to extract three parameters."

Comment: @JimB Hello JimB, that's a good point. Do you have an idea for what may be a better metric over MSE?

Comment: If you did use nonlinear regression on a histogram, could you make that explicit in your question and/or give a sample dataset?  (or even the parameters used in your "synthetic" dataset from a noncentral chi distribution along with the sample size?)  That gives something specific which would get you more targeted advice.